# How to check values in hashmap

Tags: java, loops, dictionary, arraylist, hashmap

I wanted to make a method to check if I can see if each of my piles have 6 cards in it. This is my method

```
public boolean checkIfPileHasSixCards() {

        map.put("tpile1", tpile1);
        map.put("tpile2", tpile2);
        map.put("tpile3", tpile2);
        for (ArrayList<Card> value : map.values()) {
              int size=value.size();
              if(size==6) {
                  return true;
              }
        }
        return false;

    }
```

Is my logic correct, is there a more efficient way I can iterate over the values and check if each value (ArrayList) size is 6?

Comment: oh ooops silly mistake! is everything besides that ok

Answer (score 3):

Returning `true` inside the loop is not correct - this way, your method will return `true` if **any** list in the map has six elements, not if **all** of them do. Instead, you should return `false` if a list doesn't have six elements, and only return `true` after you're done iterating the values:

```
for (List<Card> value : map.values()) {
      int size = value.size();
      if(size != 6) {
          return false;
      }
}
return true;
```

Note, by the way, that using Java 8's stream could make this snippet a lot cleaner. It won't be more efficient (it's still an O(n) operation in the worst case), but it will definitely be more concise:

```
return map.values().stream().allMatch(l -> l.size() == 6);
```

Comment: It looks to me, from the code, that the OP is creating the `Map` just to loop over it. I'm not sure the `Map` is even required.

Comment: The `size` variable is redundant, IMHO.

Comment: how else can I loop through multiple arrayLists at once?

Comment: @NicholasK I wanted to make the minimal amount of changes to make OP's code work, but I agree, you could just lose and use `value.size()` directly

Comment: @Clyde, simplest? - you have declared the variables so just hardcode it. `x1.size() == 6 && x2.size() == 6` etc

Comment: would hardcoding be effecient for 12 arrayLists that I need to check? I feel like iterating through the  HashMap would just be easier than to type it all out again. I just added two arrayLists here to check if my method was ok but I have added the other ten now.

Comment: If you have declared 12 variables, then yes @Clyde; hardcoding is efficient - think of it this way; you are _already_ hardcoding at the creation of the `Map` so why not just do the check there? There is absolutely no point to make a `Map<name, variable>` when the variables exist. If you got rid of your variables and just used a `Map` - i.e. you had a dynamic number of variables as the call site - then things would change. And the `Stream` based answer here would be the one to go for.